# how to make an array for ints and strings in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java. I simply want to make an array of `int`s and an array of `String`s.

I tried the following:

```
int() myArrayOfInts == new int(23);
String() myArrayOfStrings == new String(4);
```

I am not sure why it won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declare array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java)

Comment: You should read java tutorials...

Comment: Just change parenthesis () to square brackets []

Comment: It wont consume much time to read java tutorials to get understand what you want than posting effortless query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close. Just wrong brackets. 
It's simply `int[] myArrayOfInts = new int[23];` , for strings it is `String[] myArrayOfStrings = new String[4];`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for creating arrays is the following:

```
int[] arrayOfInts = new int[23];
String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[4];
```

See [this Java tutorials page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[]` instead of `()`. In java `==` is used for comparison so use `=` to assign any value.

Creating int array

```
  int[] myArrayOfInts = new int[3]; 
  int myArrayOfInts[] = new int[3]; //Legal but don`t use it, less readable
  int[] myArrayOfInts = {1,2,3};
```

Creating String Array

```
  String[] myArrayOfStrings = new String[2];
  String myArrayOfStrings[] = new String[2];//Legal but don`t use it, less readable
  String[] myArrayOfStrings = {"Hello","World"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use ArrayList, and may have not static size of array

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayOfInts = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
myArrayOfInts.add(5);
myArrayOfInts.add(6);

for (int a : myArrayOfInts) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

And for String:

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>(0);
myArrayOfStrings.add("Hello");
myArrayOfStrings.add("World!");
 for (String b : myArrayOfStrings) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Don't forgot to put **import java.util.ArrayList;** on the upper of file